# Do I really need to use that expensive grade of fuel?

Tags: fuel-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the benefits of premium (high octane) petrol?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-are-the-benefits-of-premium-high-octane-petrol)

The owner's manual that comes with my car says that I should use the more expensive higher octane fuel for the car. I'm extremely skeptical that I need to do this. Why would I follow this advice? What am I gaining by using the higher octane? What am I risking by using the lower octane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You should use the fuel recommended by your owner's manual.  If you don't you are increasing emissions, reducing performance and, in some circumstances, putting your car at risk of avoidable problems.

As I said over [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-are-the-benefits-of-premium-high-octane-petrol/54#54):

> High octane is required for some cars:
>   e.g., a turbocharged car will likely
>   require higher octane to reduce risk
>   of detonation with higher charge
>   temperatures. High octane is also
>   required to get the optimal power out
>   of a tuned car: properly advanced
>   timing will enhance power and economy
>   (obviously, not at the same time).
>
> Some cars are capable of utilizing the
>   highest octane available, depending on
>   the ECU programming (this is not as
>   common).
>
> Some cars can tolerate a lower octane
>   for an unspecified time by retarding
>   timing. This reduces economy and
>   increases emissions but will allow you
>   to limp home on lesser fuel.

Comment: Thanks Bob - do you have a link to a reliable source for this type of information?

Comment: @Guy, the most friendly read is Maximum Boost by Corky Bell.  Very entertaining.  The charts and graphs might lead you to believe that the narrative only applies to forced induction but the knock sensor -> timing retard also applies for naturally aspirated.  If the engine approaches knock, it will inject more fuel, retard the timing or both.