# How much Octane Fuel does Honda CBR 250R (India Version) needs? 91 or 93?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, fuel-system, compression, octane

Honda CBR250R STD 2013 Model's manual state that fuel(petrol) used should be 91 or more. Seems like they have defined the minimum threshold of RON than stating the optimum RON for the given bike.

What I want to know is can this model of CBR make use of of features of 93 Octane?

Based on your experiences fellow riders/mechanics, which did you find as the optimum RON of fuel (petrol) for this model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When given a choice between octane 89 and 93, which should I choose?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/when-given-a-choice-between-octane-89-and-93-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/will-higher-octane-fuel-improve-gas-mileage?rq=1

Comment: @Zaid: This question is not about pros and cons of different octane for a given engine but more factual question about the right octane for above specified engine.

Comment: I don't see how the possible duplicates do not answer your question. Yes, you're asking about a particular engine, but the answers in those questions are just as applicable to your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the specs call for 91 octane, use 91 octane. Using higher octane fuel will not give you better performance. Only engines which need the higher octane will see better performance from the higher octane. In most cases, engines which should use the lower octane will get worse gas mileage from the higher octane fuel.

Comment: I understand the dollar per mile aspect of higher cost fuels but how is the mileage effected by higher octane fuel?

Comment: If you consider that as octane increases, fuel actually becomes harder to burn (or more technically, is less likely to burn under compression). If it is harder to burn, it makes it less likely to burn as completely as lower octane fuel. If it is not burning as completely, you'll get lower fuel mileage. Use the gas which is specified. If you get pinging from your cycle (probably hard to detect by hearing it), you probably need a tune up and not higher octane fuel.

Comment: @Paulster2: My question wasn't about performance of higher octane fuel but what is ideal octane fuel for Honda CBR250R Indian version. It is unclear in the manual which states use 91 octane or higher.

Comment: @UtS ... If the manufacturer has specified 91 octane fuel, **this is what is going to be optimal for the motorcycle**. Higher octane fuel will cost you more and gain you nothing, but you should have no fear of damage to your engine. Lower octane fuel has the potential to damage your engine due to pre-ignition or "pinging".