# how to take petrol cars at high altitude ( plus 12000 feet)

Tags: toyota

i have Toyota Surf 3.0 L . i need to visit the places which are plus 4000 meters (15000 feet). do i need to use low octane fuel or do i need to increase the intake of fuel due to high altitude and less oxygen. please explain in detail.

Comment: Partial answers at http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/can-i-use-lower-octane-fuel-at-high-elevation. For what it's worth, I regularly drive at over 11,000 feet using ordinary fuel, etc, and haven't really noticed any differences.

Comment: By the way, 4000 meters is 13,100 feet, not 15,000.

Answer (score 1):

Carry on using your regular fuel. The BARO in your engines ECU will adjust for altitude, and O2 sensors and MAP will keep the engine running sweetly. You may notice a small drop off in power but it will not be enough to be unduly concerned.